# Can't Uninstall MySQL server

Tags: windows-10, installation, mysql, uninstall

I've tried all the answers given on similar questions but none worked.

This morning I had an issue, MySQL localhost was not running (the server was not connected, and not abled to). I thought it was a server issue so I tried all the solutions I've found (killing the task and starting manually, rebooting pc, etc), none of this worked so I ultimately opted to uninstall. But MySQL is the most sticky thing I've ever seen. I tried to run the default Windows Uninstaller, could Uninstall everything but the server (MySQL server 5.7.25). Then I tried manually deleting every MySQL folder on my computer. I did so and MySQL server still appeared on my Program List. I tried uninstalling with CCleaner, but it remained there. Just that this time program asked me a msi file, that was deleted when I deleted the MySQL folder onto ProgramData (as many answers suggested).
Then I tried to run the installer once again, but, because of an update the installer tried to install MySQL server 5.7.26 (I had 5.7.25).
Now every time I enter the installer (in faith of findind a 'Uninstall' option) I end up facing a 'Reconfigure' option. If I click it, installer gets stuck on 'Backing up MySQL database'. I don't want any database nor tables, I want to fully erase MySQL to start over again, or at least fix the connection problem I had at the very beginning (because that's why I'm going through all this trouble) but I'm stuck on an endless loop.

Right now I'm trying to install MySQL 5.7.26 (after restoring all the deleted folders that I had on the recycle bin) this time the installer gave me the option of skipping the database restoration, which I choose. But then it fails on the 'Starting the server' and I get this log

MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...

Now, I tried to run the famous MSI file I deleted and now restored, but, MySQL now tells me that there's a newer version installed (5.7.26), which, is in fact a lie, because that version never successfully ended installation...

So, how can I TOTALLY remove MySQL to start over again? What's with all this stickyness?
Any fix without actual removing would be appreciated too.

Many thanks

SYSTEM: Win10
Original installed version: mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Answer

Used RevoUninstaller, (some free option might work, I don't know).
When tried to uninstall it prompted me to re-install, so I clicked yes and solved my original problem. It performed a 'clean' reinstallation, though I don't know if it would work for complete removal of the software.